# Consolidating data from query with multiple case statements

Tags: sql, teradata

I have some data in a database formatted as such:
[image: Database design]

I have written the following SQL query to pull data from this database. Here is the query I have so far:

```
select network, 
MAX(CASE WHEN channel = 'R' and brand ='B' and spec_ind = 'x' and extended_day_ind = 'y' then 'RB30'
WHEN channel = 'R' and brand ='G' and spec_ind = 'x' and extended_day_ind = 'Y' then 'RG90'
WHEN channel = 'R' and brand ='G' and spec_ind = 'x' and extended_day_ind = 'N' then 'RB30'
WHEN channel = 'R' and brand ='G' and spec_ind = 'x' and extended_day_ind = 'N' then 'RG30' END) as Channel,
case header
    when 'Annual Shift' then value_vl end as AnnualShift,
Case header
    when 'Min' then value_vl end as MinVal,
Case Header
    when 'Max' then value_vl end as MaxVal
From mytable
WHERE network <> 'x'
group by network, value_vl, header
order by network asc
```

This query returns results as such:

[image: return]

This isn't very useful, and I would like to have this data consolidated like:

[image: how I want it]

How would I go about fixing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation, phrased like this:

```
select network, 
       (CASE WHEN channel = 'R' and brand ='B' and spec_ind = 'x' and extended_day_ind = 'y' then 'RB30'
                WHEN channel = 'R' and brand ='G' and spec_ind = 'x' and extended_day_ind = 'Y' then 'RG90'
                WHEN channel = 'R' and brand ='G' and spec_ind = 'x' and 
                     extended_day_ind = 'N' then 'RB30'
                WHEN channel = 'R' and brand ='G' and spec_ind = 'x' and extended_day_ind = 'N' then 'RG30'
        END) as Channel,
       MAX(case header when 'Annual Shift' then value_vl end) as AnnualShift,
       MAX(Case header when 'Min' then value_vl end) as MinVal,
       MAX(Case Header  when 'Max' then value_vl end) as MaxVal
From FIN_SANDBOX.asm_paid_rates_range
WHERE network <> 'x'
group by network, 
         (CASE WHEN channel = 'R' and brand ='B' and spec_ind = 'x' and extended_day_ind = 'y' then 'RB30'
              WHEN channel = 'R' and brand ='G' and spec_ind = 'x' and extended_day_ind = 'Y' then 'RG90'
              WHEN channel = 'R' and brand ='G' and spec_ind = 'x' and 
                   extended_day_ind = 'N' then 'RB30'
              WHEN channel = 'R' and brand ='G' and spec_ind = 'x' and extended_day_ind = 'N' then 'RG30'
          END)
order by network asc;
```

I don't remember if Teradata allows column aliases in the `GROUP BY`.  If so, the logic could be simplified a bit.

Comment: Teradata will allow you to use aliases just about everywhere, including group by and order by statements.